# Could not able to launch chrome browser using the selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class launch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Could not find or load main class org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the system property `webdriver.chrome.driver` as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", '/path/to/chromedriver');
```

Additionally, instead of using the **ChromeDriver** use the [**WebDriver**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) interface as follows:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. Did I make any mistake in the configuration, as I am using selenium the first time?

Comment: @AnkitPatel Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 1):

In the Launch class you are directly creating the object of ChromeDriver class without giving the chrome driver path.
So, before creating the ChromeDriver object you need to add:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path of chromedriver.exe file");
```

If you have downloaded the chrome driver exe file then you need to pass that path.
After this create the object of ChromeDriver class.